# Simple 'Greater Than' form validation

Tags: php, validation

I am trying to validate my registration form, and one of my validations doesn't work. I want to echo a error message if the first name is over 20 characters long. I am using the code

```
} else if($_POST["mem_first_name"] >20) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry but your First name is limited to 20 Characters each';
}
```

However no error is shown if more than 20 characters are entered. However if I use the same code but change it to less than like this

```
} else if($_POST["mem_first_name"] <20) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry but your First name is limited to 20 Characters each';
}
```

Then it works, is there a simple fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)  function, for counting strings? It is stable and appropriate way of counting number of characters IMO

```
} else if(strlen($_POST["mem_first_name"]) >20) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry but your First name is limited to 20 Characters each';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(strlen($_POST["mem_first_name"]) > 20)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) function

```
} else if(strlen($_POST["mem_first_name"]) >20) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry but your First name is limited to 20 Characters each';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`strlen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) function for string length checks. Also, be aware that if you need multibyte encoding support, you should switch to using [`mb_strlen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php).

```
var_dump(strlen('bär'));            // int(4) - byte length
var_dump(mb_strlen('bär', 'utf8')); // int(3) - character length
```